# How to install and import pandas from python script for specific operating system?

Tags: python, pandas, import

Is there a way for python to detect the OS and then install pandas from the file, and then import it? Basically, I need all my pandas code to function when he invokes the .py file. Please help!

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = r"C:\Users\XXXXXX\Downloads\Record.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(excel_file)
```

Comment: What have you implemented till now except reading a csv file? You can edit the question to put your research in it. Also take the StackOverflow Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,

Just add these lines before the line you "import pandas as pd":

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen("python -m pip install pandas", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
test.communicate()
```

This lines will open cmd and install pandas library then your code could import pandas.

Comment: That might not work in mac or linux. He might have to type sudo python or even python3 instead of python

Comment: That's true, these lines are for Windows, in Linux or MacOS you will need to put the command that is permitted in these OS like Javier says

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás what would the equivalent commands be for Linux and MacOS be?

Comment: I guess like: "sudo python -m pip install pandas"

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac (macOS Big Sur) I ran

python -m pip install pandas

no sudo. I was able to run my .py script which included

import pandas as pd

without an error